# Why doesn't the number updated in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to html & javascript. I want to implement an app that can generate random number and displayed in browser one by one. However, it only displays once.

The code is like below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flag = true;
        var timeout = 1;
        function generateRandom(){
            var i = 0;
            while(i < 10){
                document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = Math.ceil(300 * Math.random());
                i++;
            }

        }
    </script>

    <style> 

    </style>
    <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
    <title>Happy New Year</title>
    <h1>Happy New Year</h1>
    <hr />
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="generateRandom()">start</button>
    </div>

    <p id = "number">
        Some Text here!
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Currently you're updating the content of #number to include a random value 10 times with no delay, each time overwriting what was there previously. Changing either one of those two pieces of logic (add delay, or no overwriting) will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser only repaints the display when it isn't busy doing something else. Your while loop doesn't give it any spare time to do that in, so it won't repaint until the loop is over and the function finishes.

Even if that wasn't the case, counting to 10 doesn't take long, and it would change the numbers too rapidly for the human eye to notice.

If you want there to be a visible update then you need to:

- Allow enough time in total for the user to notice the change
- Allow enough time not running JS for the browser to perform a repaint event

For this you would generally use an interval timer.

```js
var flag = true;
var timeout = 1;

function generateRandom() {
  var i = 0,
    interval;


  function update() {
    var number;
    number = Math.ceil(300 * Math.random());
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    i++;
    if (i == 10) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }

  interval = setInterval(update, 500);

}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', generateRandom);
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button">start</button>
</div>

<p id="number">
  Some Text here!
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`while` loops are synchronous. They won't update the DOM while they are running. Nothing will be changed until the loop is done executing

This gives the appearance that nothing has happened. You should look into something that is asynchronous such as intervals/timers.